# How to get data from database using id?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am getting id value from vue to model "Zones". But in model I can't get the values from db. Below code I am using to get values.

```
  class Zones extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'zone_id';
    public function getZone($id){
         $zone = Zones::where('zone_id','=',$id)->first();

         printf($zone);
         exit(0);
    }
 }
```

Can you please help me what's wrong here?

Comment: what are you getting in print ?

Comment: check if the $id returns any value or is empty?

Comment: post your migration for zones table in your question

Comment: @samo In print I am getting blank.

Comment: @LeenaPatel $id returns the value 1.

Comment: also you could use ('zone_id',$id) instead of ('zone_id','=',$id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `print_r()` method to prints array

```
class Zones extends Model {
protected $primaryKey = 'zone_id';
public function getZone($id){
     $zone = Zones::where('zone_id','=',$id)->first();

     print_r($zone);
     exit(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: There is small mistake in your answer. print_r() do not return data, it just prints it. But if you exactly want to return data, you should use TRUE in second parameter. From php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: @LeenaPatel And one more thing I used code like if(count($zone) > 0){ }, It shows error like `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

Comment: @Kevin use `if(!empty($zone)) { }`

Comment: @LeenaPatel now showing error like `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'",`

Comment: sorry i forgot to close bracket of if statement  `if(!empty($zone)) { }`

Answer (score 1):

```
printf($var)
```

it prints normal variable string , integer etc

```
print_r($var);
```

it prints array

$zone is an array so you need to use print_r

Answer (score 0):

You could use dd($your_data) function instead of print_r() and exit(0).

There is also dump($your_data) which just prints but not dies.

Also you could use ('zone_id',$id) instead of ('zone_id','=',$id).